# ElasticSearch append non matched docs at the end of the search result

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any way to append non matched docs at the end of the search result?

I have been working on a project where we need to search docs by geolocation data but some docs don't have the geolocation data available. As a result of that these docs not returning in the search result.

Is there any way to append non matched docs at the end of the search result?

Example mapping:

```
PUT /my_locations
{
    "mappings": {
        "_doc": {
            "properties": {
                "address": {
                    "properties": {
                        "city": {
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        "location": {
                            "type": "geo_point"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Data with geo location:

```
PUT /my_locations/_doc/1
{
    "address" : {
        "city: "XYZ",
        "location" : {
            "lat" : 40.12,
            "lon" : -71.34
        }
    }
}
```

Data without geo location:

```
PUT /my_locations/_doc/2
{
    "address" : {
        "city: "ABC"
    }
}
```

Is there any way to perform geo distance query which will select the docs with geolocation data plus append the non geo docs at the end of the result?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html#query-dsl-geo-distance-query

Answer (score 1):

You have two separate queries

1. Get documents within the area
2. Get other documents

To get both of these in one search, would mean all of the documents appear in one result, and share ranking. It would be difficult to create a relevancy model which gets first 9 documents with address, and one without.

But you can just run two queries at once, one for say, the first 9 documents with location, and one for without any.

Example:

```
GET my_locations/_msearch
{}
{"size":9,"query":{"geo_distance":{"distance":"200km","pin.location":{"lat":40,"lon":-70}}}}
{}
{"size":1,"query":{"bool":{"must_not":[{"exists":{"field":"pin.location"}}]}}}
```